# P/Invoke : converting this signature to Managed c#

Tags: c#, pinvoke, unmanaged, managed

```
HRESULT WINAPI RegisterDeviceWithManagement(
  _In_ LPCWSTR ppszMDMServiceUri,
  _In_ LPCWSTR pszUPN,
  _In_ LPCWSTR ppzsAccessToken
);
```

I want to convert this to Dllimport c# signature.
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is as simple as it comes:

- The `HRESULT` type is an unsigned 32 bit integer, so `uint`. You could be justified in using `int` since signed types tend to be easier to work with in managed code. However, since you are unlikely to be performing arithmetic on an `HRESULT` you may as well use `uint` in my opinion.
- The `WINAPI` macro expands to the `stdcall` calling convention which happens to be the default, so we can omit the calling convention. If you prefer to be explicit, include `CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Stdcall`.
- The strings are all Unicode string, so we use `CharSet.Unicode`.

So the translation is:

```
[DllImport(dllname, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern uint RegisterDeviceWithManagement(
    string ppszMDMServiceUri,
    string pszUPN,
    string ppzsAccessToken
);
```

Obviously you need to fill in the name of the DLL.